# What is the meaning of the term "enrichment" when performing cross-validation?

Tags: machine-learning, correlation, cross-validation, prediction

Trying to understand a discussion of a 5-fold cross-validation process to validate a predictive model and its results, there is a particular phrase which has me stumped, i.e.:

> The predictions of the algorithm are significantly enriched with the
>   left-out test data.

**What I think it means**. Trying to understand this, the way which seems more natural for me to interpret the statement is: "When we add the left-out test data, the model is better," which seems pretty obvious.  To me, this would imply that the model needs that data - and *failed validation*.

**What it seems to me it should mean**. However, in the context of validation, I would expect something like: "There is a high degree of similarity between what our model predicted without the left-out data and said left-out data".  To me, this would imply that the model *is good at prediction*.

I believe I am not understanding the concept of enrichment.  After looking it up, the meaning is, in broad terms, "improvement".  If this is so, and therefore my first interpretation is correct, why is this important for validation?  What does "enrichment" mean in this context?

Thanks!

Comment: It would be good if you provide the source of your quote. Still, I found it by googling (http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2964116/), but even after looking up the context, the quote does not make sense to me. I do not think this word means what the authors think it means.

Comment: Thanks for filling in that missing gap.  I agree; I would think "correlation" or "success" or some similar term would make more sense.